# Appium_capybara driver + Applitools integration

Tags: capybara, appium, selenium-grid, applitools

I'm using RSpec framework with `capybara + eyes_selenium` for visual testing, and i want to integrate mobile visual testing. i installed the `appium_capybara`, and it works with a remote appium server that functions as a node in my remote selenium hub.

So far it works great, I've managed to login to my iOs simulator and interact with the page. The problem is integrating this whole thing with applitools.

i'm using the gem `eyes_selenium`, but i can't seem to perform `Eyes.open` with my `Appium::Capybara::Driver` object, getting an exception that this driver is Unknown.

```
Eyes.open(app_name: 'Applitools', test_name: test_name, viewport_size: viewport_size, driver: Capybara.page.driver)
```

anyone managed to make it work ?

Comment: What is the exact error message you get, with stack trace.

Comment: RSpec::Core::MultipleExceptionError: Unknown driver #<Appium::Capybara::Driver:0x007fcb583ac5e8>!

no stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for the `eyes_selenium` gem, the only place that error can come from is from the `eyes_driver` method - https://github.com/applitools/eyes.sdk.ruby/blob/master/lib/applitools/selenium/eyes.rb#L39 - which is implemented as below

```
def eyes_driver(driver, eyes = nil)
  if driver.respond_to? :driver_for_eyes
    driver.driver_for_eyes eyes
  elsif defined?(::Capybara::Poltergeist) && (driver.is_a? ::Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver)
    Applitools::Poltergeist::Driver.new(eyes, driver: driver)
  else
    unless driver.is_a?(Applitools::Selenium::Driver)
      Applitools::EyesLogger.warn("Unrecognized driver type: (#{driver.class.name})!")
      is_mobile_device = driver.respond_to?(:capabilities) && driver.capabilities['platformName']
      Applitools::Selenium::Driver.new(eyes, driver: driver, is_mobile_device: is_mobile_device)
    end
    raise Applitools::EyesError.new "Unknown driver #{driver}!"
  end
end
```

At a first glance the `else` section of that looks fully broken to me (why create a new instance of Applitools::Selenium::Driver just to then raise an error?). However, that leaves only a few possibilities for why it's not working for you,

1. `Appium::Capybara::Driver` is not a driver type supported by the `eyes_selenium` gem
2. You're not requiring the files needed to patch `Appium::Capybara::Driver` to be supported, such as 'applitools/capybara', although after a quick look through the eyes_selenium code I don't think it adds the `driver_for_eyes` method to any ancestor class of `Appium::Capybara::Driver` (does patch Appium::Driver though) so #1 is probably more likely.